# How to show list as read-only, but not restrict permissions?

Tags: list, permissions, list-view, read-only

I have created a list. It inherits the permissions from the site settings and that's the way it should be. I want to create a SharePoint page in which I will show the list but I don't want to allow people to add new items. Is that possible with OOB features or do I have to create something like an HTML table or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **List Settings** and **Advanced settings** you can specify that the list should be "Read only" under **Create and Edit access**.

Another option is to mirror the list, this can be done in several ways such as using *External List* if you have a content type.

Comment: I like the option of mirroring. Setting the list to read-only will not work for me, as the list does need to be editable, just not directly. Thanks!